# Switching To Data Science Field

Tags: career

I have some 14 years of work experience in operations management and education areas as Instructor of statistics and operations. I have little better command over statistical learnings. I do have a keen interest in data science learnings. Basically, want to perform a role of analyst on big data.  Will it right to make venture in Data Science field with this experience? There is touch on coding is with but do not project experiences.

Comment: So do some projects (e.g., Kaggle), write about them, and brush up on  computer science, and machine learning (I assume that's what you meant). Maybe you can negotiate a change in job title at your current job if it is close to data science? Welcome to the site and good luck!

Comment: Lasting in datascience will probably be more challenging than entering in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

As you have mentioned that you are an Instructor of Statistics I think you can directly start with different methodologies/techniques available.

As @Emre has suggested it would be better if you can work on different project available on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/), [Analytics Vidya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/). You would be exposed to most of the necessary things in Data Science field. Following [R-Bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/), will expose you to the latest packages. Ofcourse following Data Science Exchange.

You can doing small projects on different datasets on [UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php). For experimenting using different techniques.

These are just couple of things which would help you to be updated.

Follow them for atlest next 2-3 months then you can access yourself.